# Is it possible to limit character length with byte size for Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I just would like to know if it is possible to limit character length with byte size for Postgres.
It would be very appreciated if you would tell me that.

Postgres version: 9.2.17

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The length limit for a `varchar` column is in characters based on the encoding of the database. Unless you want to change your database to use a single-byte encoding (which I would strongly discourage), there is no direct way to do this.

What you can do is to use a check constraint that converts the character value to a byte array based on a specific encoding and then checks the length of the array:

```
alter table the_table
   add constraint check_byte_length 
   check ( length(convert_to(the_column, 'UTF-8')) <= 42 )
```

Comment: I appreciate for your cooperation. I did not know that I could use such a nice constraint.